# Filtering a model on a foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Alright, I am pulling my hair out (and I don't have much)  I have created a FormView that uses 2 models.  One model simply displays some information from a table (not editable) the other Model is a form that a user selects two items from a drop down box.  I need to filter the first Dropdown box. Below is the code I am using that is not working:

views.py

```
def assign_load(request):
    form = DispatchForm(request.POST or None)
    loads = Load.objects.all().filter(active=True, dispatched=False, 
                                  picked_up=False, delivered=False,
                                  billed=False, 
                                  paid=False).order_by('start_pickup_date')
    context_dict = {'dispatch' : form, 'load' : loads}
    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save()
        save_it.save()
        new_dispatch = Dispatch.objects.get(id=save_it.id)
        fix_load = Load.objects.get(id=new_dispatch.load_number_id)
        fix_load.dispatched = True
        fix_load.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dispatch/dispatch/')

    return render(request, 'dispatch/dispatch_form.html', context_dict)
```

forms.py

```
class DispatchForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dispatch
        fields = ['load_number', 'truck', 'start_mileage', 'end_mileage', 
              'pickup_date',
              'pickup_time', 'delivery_date', 'delivery_time', 'driver_pay', 
              'fuel_cost', 'miles',
              'status']

        def get_queryset(self):
            return self.model.objects.filter(load_number__dispatched=False)
```

I am trying to filter the model in forms.py I have tried using def get(), def get_queryset() and def get_context_data, none of them are returning a filtered queryset...I know I am missing something simple but I am running out of ideas any help would be great...if you need more information let me know that as well.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: But a `ModelForm` has no `queryset`. There is a difference between a `FormSet`, and a (`Model`)`Form`.

Comment: Willem, Thank you for your reply...I am new to the DJango World so I am still working things out.  From the research I have done a FormSet is used to add multiable records from the same table.  I am using 2 models. The first Model (loads) will be displayed as a list (which I have working just fine). The 2nd Model (dispatch) will allow the user to assign a load to the dispatch model.  The dispatch model as a field set as foreign key to the load model.  what I need is that once a load is assigned to a dispatch, it is no longer available.  I have flags setup but can not filter the list.